# IIS doesn't render jxr file

Tags: iis, web-config, mime, static-site

My site is hosted on IIS.

I am trying the new image format jxr, but when used in a page,it is not loaded
There is no 404 error on browser.

Older image format like jpeg loads correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who forgot about MIME settings, like me, add this to `web.config` file:

```
<staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".jxr" mimeType="image/webp" />
     <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```